# GAE better output information of appcfg.py bulkupload on daily routine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkinsert

I have a web service on Google App Engine (programmed in Python) and everyday I have to update with data from a ftp source.

My daily job, that´s outside of GAE, downloads the data from the ftp server, parse and enrich this data with other information sources and this process take nearly 2 hours.

After all this, I upload all this data to my server using the bulk upload function of the appcfg.py (command line).

Since I want to have better reports of this process, I need to know how many records were really uploaded by each call to appcfg (there more then 10)

My question is: Can I get this number of lines uploaded from the appcfg.py without having to parse its output?

Bonus question: Does anyone else do this kind of daily routine? or is it a bad practice?

Comment: Hi Gusthema,

We are interested in this as well. We also have the additional requirement of creating and indexing documents using the search api. Have you been able to find any satisfactory answers on whether using bulkupload in this manner is the right way to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: @Cygorger I didn´t find if this is the best way to do it but I´m changing all my daily routine to something different: 1 - run the batch process on google compute engine. In the end of the process, zip the output files (the ones that would be uploaded with the bulk upload) upload everything to google cloud storage and call a callback on my app engine . 2 - my app engine start reading all this files from the google cloud storage, parse them, update the database. This endpoint also start another backend call for reindexing documents . That´s working.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; we are trying something similar as well